# Error with facebook login, react-native ios expo

Tags: ios, react-native, facebook-login, expo

I have a problem with my mobile app
The problems is with the facebook login, but only in IOS
It already works in android (even in production)
Instead in IOS does not work in production, it only works in the XCODE emulator

My app.json looks like this:

```
{


"expo": {
   "name": "MyUniqueName",
   "facebookScheme":"fbMyFbAppId",
   "facebookAppId":"MyFbAppId",
   "facebookDisplayName":"MyUniqueName",
   "description": "This project is really great.",
   "slug": "MyUniqueName",
   "privacy": "public",
   "sdkVersion": "30.0.0",
   "platforms": ["ios", "android"],
   "version": "1.0.1",
   "orientation": "portrait",
   "icon": "./assets/favicon.png",
   "splash": {
     "image": "./assets/splash.png",
     "resizeMode": "cover",
   },
   "updates": {
     "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
   },
   "assetBundlePatterns": [
     "**/*"
   ],
   "ios": {
     "supportsTablet": true,
     "bundleIdentifier": "com.myCompany.myCompany",
     "infoPlist": {
       "LSApplicationQueriesSchemes": [
         "fbapi","fb-messenger-share-api","fbauth2","fbshareextension"
       ]
     }
   },
   "android": {
     "versionCode": 2,
     "package": "com.myCompany.myCompany"
   },
 }
}
```

My facebook console:
[console facebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKJEo.png)

I printed the error but only I get this:
[app screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0o14.png)

Answer (score 3):

I hope you are using **Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync**. If so,

Add **behavior: 'web'** as below.

It worked for me in Expo client and production as well.

```
Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync(Config.loginSetup.facebookID, 
 { 
 permissions: ['public_profile','email'],
 behavior: 'web'
 })
```

Comment: lic_profile','email'], behavior: 'web' - this props no-longer available in expo 35 i am facing same issue..... and this issue still open on git hub... https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/4701